# can not use xml suggestive file on android studio?

Tags: android

I'm having problems with xml files on android studio when they can not be suggested when I type View or ViewGroup
For example, I typed " (Text) will pop up a (TextView) hint ..."
If anyone knows can help me restore this. cảm ơn

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpI63.png)

Comment: Check bottom-right doctor icon in Android Studio, and choose `Inspections`. You also should put your xml code here. Maybe mistyping happens there.

Comment: thanks for the comment.
I seem to have overcome it by
- File > Invalidate caches / restart